# How to build library written by C++ and use in iOS

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, static-libraries

I now have to porting C++ code to iOS, trying to build static library by original C++ code and load the library on iOS. Because the original code is heavy, I start a small test to verify my steps could work or not.

First I need to build library (.a), which prints some string. I compile the following code and generate a library(.a) file

```
//talk.h
...
#include <iostream>
class Talk {
    Talk();
    void printHello();
    void printWord(char*);
};


//talk.cpp
#include "talk.h"
using namespace std;
void Talk::printHello() {
    cout << "Hello World";
}
void Talk::printWord(char* word) {
    cout << "Hello" << word;
}
```

The second step I try to do is open a new project for iOS app and then set link to the library file, also include corresponding "talk.h" header file.
However, some errors happen on the header file even though I build library successfully.

The errors indicate that

1. "iostream" file not found
2. "Unknown type name 'class'; did you mean 'Class'?
3. any other errors...

I have try to rename controller.m to controller.mm, but it not fixes the problem

How to import the header file written in C++ for using library on iOS?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

A rough outline:

In Xcode (starting with an either one of the template iOS Application projects (or an existing one):

- *Create a new static library target*: **File -> New -> Target....** Select **Framework Or Library**, and then **Cocoa Touch Static Library**
- *Add library source code*: Drag library source code into Xcode project.  In the dialog that appears,  select the build target created above.
- *Add project dependancy to library*: Select Project in Project Navigation, the the iOS build target from Targets. Select **Build Phases** tab, then under **Target Dependancies** in the window, click on the **+** sign. A sheet opens (**choose items to add**) and the library target should be at thee top of the list.
- *Include Library in iOS Target*: Under **Link Binary with Libraries**, click +. The library (a .a file) should be at the top of the list.
- *Link with libc++*: As the step above. Select **libc++** from the list.
- *Enable Objective-C++ compilation* for any source code file that needs to include the library headers by changing the extension from .m to .mm
- Build the iOS application target.

Xcode will have taken care of setting everything else up for you, including compiler flags and header search paths.

Answer (score 0):

For the 1st part C++ compiles well with Xcode 
I have written a simple tutorial 
http://tutorialsios.blogspot.com/2013/09/c-beginers-code-for-objective-c.html
These code were written using Xcode and compiled in terminal

```
#include "functionOverLoading.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
..
..
       return 0;
    }
```

> $g++ functionOverLoading.cpp –o functionOverLoading
>
> $ ./functionOverLoading

Comment: but what I want is build a library from C++ code and then use the library on iOS, which needs load library and include open interface header in iOS project. Not run plain C++ code in Xcode

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the C++ Standard Library.

To do this, find Other Linker Flags in your project and add `-lstdc++`.

Comment: How to add? and Where to add?